# How do I get Unity to inject a reference to HttpSessionState to a service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unity-container, session-state

*Disclaimer: I have a fair bit of experience with DI containers but am quite new to Unity.*

I have an MVC project that is all wired up with Unity DI using constructor injection and works great.  But I now have a service that I want to inject into my controllers (and maybe places other than controllers at some point) and this service needs access to ASP.NET session state. The service's purpose is to manage a list in session and I don't want the list mechanics in my controller.

I realize I could add a Setup method to the service (and it's interface) that my controller could call, passing in a reference to the Session, before using the service, but I don't like that as I may want to make an implementation of the service that uses something other than Session for my state management and also it is implementation specifics leaking into my interface. I also realize I can use HttpContext.Current in my service but I don't want to do that for many reasons, particularly for the issues it creates for unit testing.

Can Unity inject a reference to HttpSessionState into the service's constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple ways to do this. The easiest is probably to use an injection factory:

```
container.RegisterType<HttpSessionState>(
    new InjectionFactory(c => { return HttpContext.Current.Session; }));
```

Then anywhere you have a dependency on the HttpSessionState in the graph, the delegate given will run and pull it out of HttpContext.Current.

Of course, this only works if you're doing a new resolve per request.