# Setting Session data in another Controller

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC project, which has these two controllers `ReportsController` and `ReportViewerController`.

I have a method in `ReportsController` which I am calling from ajax

```
    public void Report(ReportWrapper pW)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> pParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        pParameters.Add("GroupIdents", pW.pGroupIdents);

        ReportViewerController rvc = new ReportViewerController();
        rvc.Session = Session; // Can't be assigned to
        rvc.SetReportValues(pW.pReportName, pParameters);
    }
```

Which I want to call this method in `ReportViewerController`

```
    public void SetReportValues(string pReportName, Dictionary<string, object> pParameters)
    {
        Session["ReportName"] = pReportName;
        Session["ReportParameters"] = pParameters;
    }
```

But the Session in `ReportViewerController` is null, how do I setup/initialise it?

Comment: you should wrap common code (SetReportValues method) into service layer

Comment: Say, hypothetically, I didn't know what service layer was, and Googleing it didn't explain clearly either

Answer (score 0):

use a service (helper) classes to share common code between controllers:

```
public class ReportService()
{
   public void SetReportValues(string pReportName, Dictionary<string, object> pParameters)
   {
      HttpContext.Current.Session["ReportName"] = pReportName;
      HttpContext.Current.Session["ReportParameters"] = pParameters;
   }
}
```

ReportsController:

```
public void Report(ReportWrapper pW)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> pParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    pParameters.Add("GroupIdents", pW.pGroupIdents);

    var reportService = new ReportService();     
    reportService.SetReportValues(pW.pReportName, pParameters);
}
```

ReportViewerController:

```
public void SetReportValues(string pReportName, Dictionary<string, object> pParameters)
{
    var reportService = new ReportService();     
    reportService.SetReportValues(pW.pReportName, pParameters);
}
```

This example uses HttpContext class and manual service initialization which is not a ideal way how to do this because it makes difficult to test/extend your code. A better approach would be to rely on interfaces rather then concrete implementation and use dependency injection to inject these dependencies into your controllers:

http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/asp-net-mvc-moving-code-from-controller-action-to-service-layer
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-dependency-injection
[How do I get Unity to inject a reference to HttpSessionState to a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15908400/how-do-i-get-unity-to-inject-a-reference-to-httpsessionstate-to-a-service)

Comment: I went with a static method overload in ReportViewerController that accepts the Session as a parameter instead. But I take it that ServiceLayer is not a provision in MVC projects, rather it is a posh name for utility class

Comment: @MajoB This won't work as the `Session` object doesn't exist. The best approach is to inject the session via dependency injection.

Comment: @JoeMighty why not? he can place this class into web project in services folder. I've just simplified my answer but I agree with you that injecting the session into the service will be the cleanest solution.

Comment: @MajoB Because the `Session` object is a property within MVC's base controller, not the `ReportService`. If you wanted to reference the session object within `ReportService` and drop the `ReportService` into the web project's folder then you'd need to reference the `HttpContext.Session` directly - which isn't the best solution and should be avoided. Granted it will work, but it's far from ideal.

Comment: @JoeMighty yes, I forgot about HttpContext